# How to Create http Web Request in Windows Phone Silverlight Project?

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to make an Http Post and get response from Windows Phone App...Here is how I would have done it in ASP.net.

```
string strUrl =  "http://....."; 
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( s );
string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
s.Close();
readStream.Close();
```

But I cannot do this as it gives an error that GetResponse method cannot be Used in Silverlight Project. What is an alternative to this and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Most methods that cause blocking behaviour have been eliminated from the WP/Silverlight APIs (the idea here is not to give the developer any opportunity to inadvertently lock up the UI).

Synchronous IO falls into this category.

You need to rewrite your method using [`async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) methods:

```
public async Task<SomeReturnType> MyMethod()
{
    //...
    HttpWebResponse response = 
        (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync()); 
    //...

}
```

Comment: I am a complete newbie and i don't know how to implement this. Can you provide me links where i can read more abou this?

Comment: I did. `async` is a link above. It links here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: How to ignore Https Ceritificate in HttpWebRequest?

Comment: @SunilKumarSC How about opening a question to ask that ?

Comment: Ya Sure..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341536/how-to-get-the-download-upload-statusin-from-http-client-in-windows-8-1-univ