# How to get the Download/Upload status(in %) from Http Client in Windows 8.1 Universal App?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a spec in which there is a need to ignore HTTPS certificates and also to get the status of Upload/Download.

I am using HttpClient to ignore the certificate but i could not find the way to get the status of downloading/Uploading.

I know it was there in WebClient Windows Phone 8 and Webclient not there in Windows 8.1.

So please guide me to accomplish both these things.

Answer (score 1):

For Download progress, You can return response stream from your Http request and can use below code to write to file which also display progress status

```
 IInputStream inputStream = null;
            IRandomAccessStream fs = null;
            try
            {
                inputStream = responseStream.AsInputStream();
                ulong totalBytesRead = 0;
                fs = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                ulong fileSize = Convert.ToUInt64(Size);

                while (true)
                {
                    // Read from the web.
                    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(512);
                        buffer = await inputStream.ReadAsync(
                           buffer,
                           buffer.Capacity,
                           InputStreamOptions.None);

                        if (buffer.Length == 0)
                        {
                            // There is nothing else to read.
                            break;
                        }


                        // Report progress.

                        totalBytesRead += buffer.Length;

                        double progress = ((double)totalBytesRead / fileSize);
                        double Value = progress * 100;

                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bytes read: {0}", totalBytesRead);

                        await fs.WriteAsync(buffer);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inputStream.Dispose();
                        fs.Dispose();

                        await file.DeleteAsync();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                inputStream.Dispose();
                fs.Dispose();


        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

For upload Progress, there is no in built support to do that, but you can use 
[ProgressMessageHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.handlers.progressmessagehandler(v=vs.118).aspx)  found in System.Net.Http.Handler which you can found on Nuget and than hook that to your HttpClient Object.

Comment: Ya I already did this but I am getting only Sent Content Status but not total bytes to be received(I am getting Total Bytes to be received = 0B) that means I am getting only 50 % status.

Comment: @SunilKumarSC I don't know how your server API is implemented, but you need to know file size in advance to track download progress.

Comment: Ok I got it 

Thank u very much